# Index out of range, when it's not. VB.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list

I have written this code in VB.net and I'm trying to figure out why it's throwing this error,

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

even though I know the index is not out of range.

```
Dim logbookServer As List(Of String) = webClient.DownloadString("http://localhost/serverlogbook.csv").Split(",").ToList

If webClient.IsBusy Then
    Dim status = webClient.IsBusy
    While status = True
        status = webClient.IsBusy
    End While
End If

For i As Integer = 0 To logbookServer.Count - 1
    Dim line As List(Of String) = logbookServer(i).Split("|").ToList
    If line(1) <> "JBU" + myID.ToString Then
        logbookServer.RemoveAt(i)
    End If
Next
```

It throws the error at `If line(1) <> "JBU" + myID.ToString Then` on the `line(1)` reference. Even when I placed `MsgBox(line(1))` on the line before, it returns the appropriate value, then when I close out of the message box it throws the error on that. I've placed several message boxes prior to the location where it throws the error to verify that there actually is a value there, and it returns the value that I expect, including the correct string from `logbookServer` to parse. So I'm really not sure why it's throwing the error.

Comment: Maybe not related to the issue, but as you're using `.RemoveAt`, you should be running your loop backwards: `For i As Integer = logbookServer.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1`

Comment: If you're deleting items, you can't iterate forward. Think about it for a few minutes. Deleting an item removes it from that spot,which renumbers all of the items after that point. You're cutting off the branch you're standing on. When you get that error, trust the interpreter - you're really going out of bounds. It cannot be wrong, because it's executing the code and knows what's happening. It's always the code's fault.

Comment: @MarkL oh that makes sense, thanks! Still throwing the error, but you saved me an extra headache, haha.

Comment: To make it more clear: Imagine 3 items in the list. The valid indexes are 1, 2 and 3. You check the item at index 1 and decide it should be removed. That moves the items at indexes 2 and 3 to now be at index 1 and 2 (because the Index item was deleted), but your iterator is still at index 1. It gets incremented, and item 2 (previously item 3) is now checked. You decide to keep it, and the iterator is incremented to 3. There is no item at 3 any longer because of the renumbering when you delted item 1. *Index out of bounds*.

Comment: @KenWhite yes that concept makes complete sense, thank you for explaining in detail! However the ```line``` list isn't what's being iterated with the for loop. True, it would make sense if I was indexing ```logbookServer```, but it's still throwing the error on the list I'm declaring _within_ the for loop. Also I've verified that the correct value is there and is being referenced. I'm not removing items from ```line```, I'm removing them from ```logbookServer```. I'm sure its just an error I haven't had to work through yet. Still learning, haha.

Comment: You're looping through `logbookServer` with your `for` loop. You're deleting items from `logbookServer` with `logbookServer.RemoveAt(i)`. What I wrote above is absolutely applicable to the problem youre having. If you remove an item from a list *inside the loop that is iterating that list* in a forward order, you'll get an index out of bounds error as I described above. What else you're dong inside that loop is irrelevant. The error might first show up at the point you're referencing the list to `Split()` a line, because you've run off the end of the list as I described in my prior comment.

Answer (score 0):

Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

You need to go backwards through the list when you are removing elements of the list. .Split is expecting a Char. The small c following the character to split by tells the compiler that this is a Char. Although + will work as a concatenation operator the ampersand (&) is usually used.

```
    For i As Integer = logbookServer.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Dim line As List(Of String) = logbookServer(i).Split("|"c).ToList
        If line(1) <> "JBU" & myID.ToString Then
            logbookServer.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next
```